# Referencing relative directories outside of project

Tags: python, django

In one of my apps, I want to load some data from another directory on my machine. My Django project is located at `C:/Projects/MyProject`, my app is located at `C:/Projects/MyProject/myapp`, and my data directory is located at `C:/Data/MyAppData`. For various reasons, I do not want to store this data directly in the app's static directory. How can I do this?

Here is what I have tried. In `C:/Projects/MyProject/settings.py`, I have the following:

```
import os
DATA_ROOT = `C:/Data`
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'MyAppData')
```

But how do I now reference `DATA_DIR` in my views file?

Also, suppose that I want to keep everything relative, and avoid hard-coding `C:/Data`. Is this possible? Something like the following:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '../../../Data'
DATA_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'MyAppData')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BASE_DIR + '../../../Data'` does not contains appropriate separate in between. Use `os.path.join` there, too.

BTW, `os.path.join` accepts multiple arguments. So you can write as follow:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../../Data', 'MyAppData')

# To get absolute path
DATA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../../Data', 'MyAppData'))
```

To access the `DATA_ROOT` in views, import `settings` in the view:

```
from django.conf import settings

# Do something with `settings.DATA_ROOT`
```

**UPDATE**

If you use Python 3.4+, you can  use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
DATA_ROOT = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parents[3] / 'Data' / 'MyAppData'
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I now reference DATA_ROOT in my views file?

Comment: @Karnivaurus, I updated the answer to include the usage of the `DATA_ROOT` in the view file.